# Orthographic/Perspective Views in Paraview

Tags: paraview

**Problem**: In `Paraview 5.6.0`, for an arbitrary geometry, the *view directions* can be set for the side, front, top views (shown below) by one-click.

However, the display of either **an orthographic view or a perspective view** (or any standard [projected views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection)) is not short-cut (e.g. bottom-left subfigure), unlike other software, e.g. [ANSYS](http://www.afs.enea.it/project/neptunius/docs/fluent/html/ug/node910.htm).

[image]

**Attempts**:

The side, front, top view directions can be set simply by clicking a `Set view direction to` button below if `View->Toolbars->Camera Controls` is on.

[image]

I explored `Adjust Camera` button, which gives the complete control on projection views. Nevertheless, it is difficult to adjust for a novice.

[image]

Is there any shortcut in `Paraview` to obtain a standard orthographic or perspective view?

PS: Google-search was fruitless to me as well. I also might completely miss the correct terminology for **views**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shortcut but adding one should not be a lot of work.
Feel free to open an issue in our [gitlab](https://www.gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview)

However, if you've configured it once manually, you can save the viewpoint in the Adjust Camera dialog or using the viewpoints toolbar.

Also you will want to enable `Camera Parallel Projection`.

Comment: Thanks; but what is the reason that I may want to enable `Camera Parallel Projection`?

Comment: Side, Front, and Top view require it to have a true orthographic projection.

Comment: In addition to @MathieuWestphal answer, axonometric views (such as isometric, dimetric or trimetric views) are only defined in terms of orthographic projection, i.e. for `Camera Parallel Projection`.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to define additional views in Paraview, you can set `Custom Viewpoints` under `Layout` > `Adjust Camera` (small icon in layout view next to `2D/3D` switch at the right).

Starting from `-Z` view, one can set the azimuth and elevation angles to obtain the following views (in accordance to SolidWorks standard views):

#### Isometric view:

```
Azumith = +45°
Elevation = +35.264°
```

#### Dimetric view:

```
Azumith = +20.43°
Elevation = +19.244°
```

#### Trimetric view:

```
Azumith = +27.368°
Elevation = +31.174°
```

For other user-defined views you can use the following equations to calculate the azimuth angle [image: \gamma] and the elevation angle [image: \delta]:

[image: azimuth_angle]

[image: elevation_angle]

[image: angle_picture]

Ref.: Brian Griffith: "Engineering Drawing for Manufacture", Elsevier, 2003. ISBN 978-1-85718-033-6, DOI https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-1-85718-033-6.X5012-5

Comment: I'm just curious what book or article is the picture in your post? I'd be interested to learn more about this.

Comment: I just added a reference to the book under the picture.